# Place posted form data into a custom api end point using ngResource AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ngresource

I have been tasked with creating a new custom api end point which I want to call "associate" within the existing Club resource, I have created a new feature to the resource called "associate" which should then "post" the selected data from a form which is created with input tag directives and place them into a new JSON Blob, which is attached to the parent blob for example:

<----JSON Below is just an example ---->

```
[
    {
    "property": X,
    "property": "X",
    "property": null,
    "property": 0,
    "associate": [
          {
               "associated": {
               "id": "X",
               }
          }
     ]
    }
 ]
```

Here is the resource:

```
angular.module('AppResource')
.factory('Club', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    'use strict';

    return $resource('/api/v1/users/:user_id/clubs/:club_id',
        {
            club_id: '@id',
            user_id: '@user_id'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            delete: {
                method: 'DELETE'
            },
            associate: {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/v1/users/:user_id/clubs/:club_id/associate'
            }
        });
}]);
```

I don't seem to be able to get the form to send this data to this new custom end point with the following javascript in my controller, this below code is what is causing the error in the console:

```
//additional programming above relates to other aspects of the view//

},function (assign) {
                Club.$associate({user_id: assign.user_id, club_id: assign.id}, {
                    club_account_id: assign.club_account.name
                });

//club_account_id relates to another injected resource which determines
//the details within each club account. I need the property
//club_account.name to be sent from the form when captured 
//by the input tag directive
```

Error: angular.min.js:114 TypeError: Cannot read property 'club_account' of undefined

HTML:

the view uses the tag-input directive.

```
<div class="col-md-7">
                <tags-input class="form-control" ng-model="form.club_accounts" replace-spaces-with-dashes="false" add-from-autocomplete-only="true" placeholder="Start Typing an Club Name">
                    <auto-complete source="club_accounts"></auto-complete>
                </tags-input>
</div>
```

I've tried loads of different things but still get TypeError Reference where cannot read property id of undefined.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show all relevant code context and provide details from error as to where it gets thrown within that code

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: Hi @charlietfl I have added further details to the problem. I hope this makes it easier to see what I am trying to do.